# Laravel auth::check не срабатывает

Tags: laravel

Почему не срабатывает auth::check

в методе контроллера прописываю

```
if (Auth::check){
 код
}else return response()->json([
  'error' => 1,
  'message' => 'Нужно авторизоваться'
]);
```

но не работает проверка, если пользователь не авторизован

Comment: Что значит "не работает проверка, если пользователь не авторизован"? Что выводит и/или что в логах? И почему `if (Auth::check)`, если должн быть `if (Auth::check())`?

Comment: не дописал if (Auth::check()),просто выполняет код для авторизованных